IAM to limit RDS sharing to certain accounts
I have a multi-account AWS setup. I'm running an automatic weekly process that takes a database snapshot and shares it from Account A to Account B. For this, I'd like to ensure that the IAM role (that lives in Account A) sharing the snapshot is only allowed to share with a specific account ID belonging to Account B - i.e. sharing to account B is permitted - sharing to account C is denied. Is this possible?
I've tried using a variety of the IAM conditions but nothing seems to have done the trick.
Examples below of what I've tried
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:<removed>:snapshot:*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalAccount": "<target account ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:ModifyDBSnapshotAttribute",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:<removed>:snapshot:*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceAccount": "<target account ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

